# Platform not supported-to check the Java VM properties

Tags: java, jvm, java-6

While running an application, I am getting this as error-

"platform not supported,check Vm properties os.name and os.arch.
No Java found, pls install java"
whereas I do have Java 32 and 64 bit. My path is set for 64 bit but even changing the path didnt resolve the issue.
This application runs on 32 bit Java-1.6.0

Comment: Try fully qualifying the java executable: `C:\path\to\jdk\bin\java.exe -classpath . MyClass` or whatever classpath and class name you use.

Comment: @Gurveer - you should always paste the actual message you get, don't re-type it. For example, I expect it actually says _"please"_, not _"pls"_. While that difference is not important, re-typing _can_ introduce mistakes in the message that may prevent people from being able to help you.

Comment: Are you sure you have a 64-bit OS? Which version is it?  Have you tried to use a more up to date version of Java as a newer version might not work?